# Get the last 4 weeks prior to current week of and the same 4 weeks of last year

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a list of date, fiscal week, and fiscal year:

```
DATE_VALUE  FISCAL_WEEK FISCAL_YEAR_VALUE
14-Dec-20   51          2020
15-Dec-20   51          2020
16-Dec-20   51          2020
17-Dec-20   51          2020
18-Dec-20   51          2020
19-Dec-20   51          2020
20-Dec-20   51          2020
21-Dec-20   52          2020
22-Dec-20   52          2020
23-Dec-20   52          2020
24-Dec-20   52          2020
25-Dec-20   52          2020
26-Dec-20   52          2020
27-Dec-20   52          2020
28-Dec-20   1           2021
29-Dec-20   1           2021
30-Dec-20   1           2021
31-Dec-20   1           2021
1-Jan-21    1           2021
2-Jan-21    1           2021
3-Jan-21    1           2021
4-Jan-21    2           2021
5-Jan-21    2           2021
6-Jan-21    2           2021
7-Jan-21    2           2021
8-Jan-21    2           2021
9-Jan-21    2           2021
10-Jan-21   2           2021
11-Jan-21   3           2021
12-Jan-21   3           2021
13-Jan-21   3           2021
14-Jan-21   3           2021
15-Jan-21   3           2021
16-Jan-21   3           2021
17-Jan-21   3           2021
18-Jan-21   4           2021
19-Jan-21   4           2021
20-Jan-21   4           2021
21-Jan-21   4           2021
22-Jan-21   4           2021
23-Jan-21   4           2021
24-Jan-21   4           2021
20-Dec-21   52          2021
21-Dec-21   52          2021
22-Dec-21   52          2021
23-Dec-21   52          2021
24-Dec-21   52          2021
25-Dec-21   52          2021
26-Dec-21   52          2021
27-Dec-21   53          2021
28-Dec-21   53          2021
29-Dec-21   53          2021
30-Dec-21   53          2021
31-Dec-21   53          2021
1-Jan-22    53          2021
2-Jan-22    53          2021
3-Jan-22    1           2022
4-Jan-22    1           2022
5-Jan-22    1           2022
6-Jan-22    1           2022
7-Jan-22    1           2022
8-Jan-22    1           2022
9-Jan-22    1           2022
10-Jan-22   2           2022
11-Jan-22   2           2022
12-Jan-22   2           2022
13-Jan-22   2           2022
14-Jan-22   2           2022
15-Jan-22   2           2022
16-Jan-22   2           2022
17-Jan-22   3           2022
18-Jan-22   3           2022
19-Jan-22   3           2022
20-Jan-22   3           2022
21-Jan-22   3           2022
22-Jan-22   3           2022
23-Jan-22   3           2022
24-Jan-22   4           2022
25-Jan-22   4           2022
26-Jan-22   4           2022
27-Jan-22   4           2022
28-Jan-22   4           2022
29-Jan-22   4           2022
30-Jan-22   4           2022
```

I want to pull the last 4 weeks prior to the current week AND the same 4 weeks of the year before. Please see [example 1](https://dbfiddle.uk/z8b6ZBiD). This works fine when all 4 weeks are within the same year. But when it comes to the beginning of a year when 1 or more weeks are in the current year but the other are in the previous year, I am not able to get the desired output below:

```
FISCAL_YEAR_VALUE   FISCAL_WEEK
2020                51
2020                52
2021                2
2021                1
2021                52
2021                53
2022                1
2022                2
```

The code I have is below. I am using the date of 21-JAN-22 as an example:

```
SELECT 
  FISCAL_YEAR_VALUE,
  FISCAL_WEEK
FROM TABLE_NAME  

WHERE FISCAL_YEAR_VALUE IN (SELECT * 
FROM (WITH T AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT FISCAL_YEAR_VALUE
    FROM TABLE_NAME
    WHERE TRUNC(DATE_VALUE) <= TRUNC(TO_DATE('21-JAN-22'))--TEST DATE
    ORDER BY FISCAL_YEAR_VALUE DESC
    FETCH NEXT 2 ROWS ONLY
               )
SELECT FISCAL_YEAR_VALUE
FROM T ORDER BY FISCAL_YEAR_VALUE
    )   
                                )                            
AND FISCAL_WEEK IN (SELECT *
FROM (WITH T AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT FISCAL_WEEK, FISCAL_YEAR_VALUE
    FROM TABLE_NAME 
    WHERE TRUNC(DATE_VALUE) <= TRUNC(TO_DATE('21-JAN-22'))--TEST DATE
    ORDER BY FISCAL_YEAR_VALUE DESC, FISCAL_WEEK DESC
    OFFSET 1 ROWS
    FETCH NEXT 4 ROWS ONLY
                )
SELECT FISCAL_WEEK
FROM T ORDER BY FISCAL_YEAR_VALUE, FISCAL_WEEK
    )    
                    )
GROUP BY FISCAL_YEAR_VALUE, FISCAL_WEEK
ORDER BY FISCAL_YEAR_VALUE, FISCAL_WEEK
```

Output of the code is:

```
FISCAL_YEAR_VALUE   FISCAL_WEEK
2021                2
2021                1
2021                52
2021                53
2022                1
2022                2
```

As you can see, the last 2 weeks of year 2020 are not included. Please see [example 2](https://dbfiddle.uk/nF_s_fZM). How can I also include this exception in the code to make it dynamic? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please [edit] the question include a [MRE] describe how to calculate which week is in which fiscal year. Also, questions on Stack Overflow must be self-contained; while the links may provide examples of your tables, data and query, it is better to include the essential parts of the question here and provide the link for reference. Links can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

To find the values this year, you can use:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT fiscal_year_value, fiscal_week
FROM   table_name
WHERE  date_value <  TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW')
AND    date_value >= TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') - INTERVAL '28' DAY
```

To find the values from the previous year, you can find the maximum fiscal week from this year and subtract 1 from the year and then use that to find the upper bound of the `date_value` for last fiscal year and, given that can use a similar range for last year:

```sql
WITH this_year (fiscal_year_value, fiscal_week) AS (
  SELECT fiscal_year_value, fiscal_week
  FROM   table_name
  WHERE  date_value <  TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW')
  AND    date_value >= TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') - INTERVAL '28' DAY
),
max_last_year (max_date_value) AS (
  SELECT MAX(date_value) + INTERVAL '1' DAY
  FROM   table_name
  WHERE  (fiscal_year_value, fiscal_week) IN (
           SELECT fiscal_year_value - 1, fiscal_week
           FROM   this_year
           ORDER BY fiscal_year_value DESC, fiscal_week DESC
           FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
         )
)
SELECT fiscal_year_value, fiscal_week
FROM   this_year
UNION
SELECT t.fiscal_year_value, t.fiscal_week
FROM   table_name t
       INNER JOIN max_last_year m
       ON (   t.date_value <  m.max_date_value
          AND t.date_value >= m.max_date_value - INTERVAL '28' DAY);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
Create Table table_name(DATE_VALUE DATE, FISCAL_WEEK INT, FISCAL_YEAR_VALUE INT);

INSERT INTO table_name (date_value, fiscal_week, fiscal_year_value)
  SELECT DATE '2019-12-30' + LEVEL - 1, CEIL(LEVEL/7), 2020
  FROM   DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 7 * 52
UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2020-12-28' + LEVEL - 1, CEIL(LEVEL/7), 2021
  FROM   DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 7 * 53
UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2022-01-03' + LEVEL - 1, CEIL(LEVEL/7), 2022
  FROM   DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 7 * 52;
```

Outputs:

| FISCAL_YEAR_VALUE | FISCAL_WEEK |
| --- | --- |
| 2022 | 38 |
| 2022 | 39 |
| 2022 | 40 |
| 2022 | 41 |
| 2021 | 38 |
| 2021 | 39 |
| 2021 | 40 |
| 2021 | 41 |

And if today's date was 2022-01-01, would output:

| FISCAL_YEAR_VALUE | FISCAL_WEEK |
| --- | --- |
| 2021 | 52 |
| 2021 | 53 |
| 2022 | 1 |
| 2022 | 2 |
| 2020 | 51 |
| 2020 | 52 |
| 2021 | 1 |
| 2021 | 2 |

There may be a simpler method but without any knowledge of how you calculate a fiscal year that is not immediately possible.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ehNjhYPY)